# is it possible to detect the moment that slide animation ends when window minimization is restored?

Tags: windows, winapi

Click the minimized window on the taskbar to restore it.
At this time, the slide animation is played and restored.
Can i detect when the animation ends?

This message is generated the moment it is clicked.
(WM_ACTIVATE, SC_RESTORE)

Is there no message at the time when it is completely restored to the screen?

Comment: Why would that message be useful? Phrased differently: What do you need to do but cannot do before the window animation has run to completion?

Comment: i want do something just after the window animation has restored

Comment: Exactly what is that "something"?

Comment: I am trying to open a secondary window to decorate the window. 
However, the sub window is displayed first before the parent window is displayed.
I want to show the secondary window after the parent window is completely restored.

Comment: Have you tried to handle `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`?

Comment: I've tried, as far as I know, on WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED , but it didn't work.

Comment: If you need to put adornments on windows, you'll have to do it from the window itself. You cannot force your idea of how things are supposed onto the system. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: You can disable the transition animation altogether for your window, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121003-00/?p=6423. Otherwise there's no way to track it.

Comment: I don't want to force something the system doesn't provide.
I'm asking the question to figure it out because I don't know if the system gives me what I want or not.
Is it that the system doesn't provide what I'm looking for?

Comment: I like window min/restore slide animation. I don't want to disable animation, so I asked the question.
If it's clear that the system doesn't offer it, I'll look for another way.

Comment: You could use Spy++ to track all messages and see if there is something else.

Comment: I tried to make an sub window appear in the messages that occurred during restoration.
However, the sub window appeared before the main window was completely restored.
So, because winapi history is old, I thought there might be someone who had the same problem and solved it.
Is there no one in long history who has solved the same problem as me? ^^;

Comment: I had a look at the source of a toolbar that I once wrote, which attaches to some common dialogs. It uses a CBT hook and handles `HCBT_ACTIVATE` event. Then it subclasses the window and handles `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`. The first time it receives this message it posts a private, registered message to the window. When it receives this message, it finally shows the window. The window animation looks good, the toolbar appears in the correct position and gets animated together with the hooked window.

Comment: I got this technique of using `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` to post a private message from the [OldNewThing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) blog, which is the best source for "historic" WinAPI knowledge.

Comment: Can you tell me which post in oldNewThing? 
As mentioned above, it could not be implemented with WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message.
This is because the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message occurs before the window is completely restored.
For reference, the sub window I'm talking about is not a child.
Nevertheless, I would like to see if what you said solves the problem.

Comment: zett42 mentioned that it should be [this article blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080115-00/?p=23813), which is Raymond's explanation of the use of WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED.

Comment: I tried again with WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED. However, this message occurs before the restore animation ends. So the secondary window appears before the parent window is fully restored. ㅠㅜ